# How do I join two distinct select statements to return any matching results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with account information.  Table1 has account types and account numbers. Table2 has account names and account statuses. I want to return a list of accounts from Table1 based on a condition (i.e., AccountNumber = '100' or '300') and join it to records that match conditions in Table2 (i.e.g, AccountStatus = 'active').

Table 1

```
AccountType - School
AccountType - School
AccountType - School
AccountNumber - 100
AccountNumber - 200
AccountNumber - 300
```

Table 2

```
AccountName - Tuition Expense
AccountName - Car Expense
AccountName - Food Expense
AccountStatus - Active
AccountStatus - Inactive
AccountStatus - Active
```

Account Number - 100
Account Number - 200
Account Number - 300

So I can return (Accounts that are '100' or '300' and are 'Active'):

Table 3

```
AccountType - School
AccountType - School
AccountNumber - 100 
AccountNumber - 300
AccountName - Tuition Expense
AccountName - Food Expense
AccountStatus - Active
AccountStatus - Active

SELECT Table1.AccountNumber
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.AccountNumber IN ('100', '300') INNER JOIN
      Table2
      ON Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountName
WHERE Table2.AccountStatus = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: Your data sample is not clear

Comment: I updated the data in both tables. Ultimately, I want to apply conditions to Table1 and return all values that match conditions in Table2.

Comment: accountumber in table1 is numeric and accountname in table2 is a string, you can not make a join with these 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot join Table 1 with Table 2 unless you have a common field in both tables. Are you missing any other table to post here?

Comment: Ah, yes. Table2 has AccountNumber (same as Table1).

Comment: Ok, so this should give you correct result: SELECT Table1.AccountNumber
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountNumber
WHERE Table1.AccountNumber IN ('100', '300') 
AND Table2.AccountStatus = 'ACTIVE'

Comment: Thank you. That answers my original question. I think I need something more along the lines of, if there is an AccountNumber '100' then there must be an AccountNumber '300'. So if AccountNumber = '100' exists and AccountNumber '300' exists then return 'Verified'. If AccountNumber = '100' exists and there is no AccountNumber '300', return 'Unverified'.

Comment: Could you please further elaborate this along with sample output you want?

Comment: So Table1 has AccountUniqueID, AccountNumber, AccountTypeNumber. Table2 has AccountName, AccountNumber, AccountStatus.

I want to return AccountNumber and a message 'Pass' when AccountNumber has an AccountTypeNumber that = '100' and AccountStatus = 'Active'. The issue is that there are several entries for each AccountNumber and I only want to return the full unique list of AccountNumbers and then 'Pass' or 'Fail' given it has a matching AccountTypeNumber of '100' and AccountStatus of 'Active' as 'Pass' and all else 'Fail'.

Comment: I have SELECT Distinct AccountNumber, CASE WHEN Count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber) > 1 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS 'Account Verification' WHERE AccountTypeNumber = '100'

Comment: I think you cannot achieve this unless you establish a link between AccountNumber 100 and 300 for each record. I tried this: SELECT Table1.AccountType, Table1.AccountNumber, Table2.AccountName, Table2.AccountStatus 
, CASE WHEN (
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountNumber
WHERE Table1.AccountNumber = '300'
) >= 1 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS 'Account Verification'
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountNumber
WHERE Table1.AccountNumber IN ('100', '300') 
AND Table2.AccountStatus = 'ACTIVE'